# Google Cloud Platform load balancer aborts large file upload requests

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, file-upload, google-cloud-platform

When uploading (multipart post) file which is by underlying backend application (tomcat using apache fileupload library) considered as too large and responded with 413 http status, original request is aborted on load balancer with "aborted_request_due_to_backend_early_response" status. This means that user is presented with some built-in system error page instead of application error page.

How should the system be configured to deliver application error response to end user through load-balancer?

Some other details:

- when the limit is, for example, 2MB, and the uploaded file is ~5MB, everything works fine, but when the file is >6MB described behaviour occurs (this depends on user's connection quality)
- tomcat's / servlet's maxPostSize maxFileSize ... does not make any change
- returning 200 instead of 413 does not make any change

I assume, that the response is (for those large ~6MB files) returned back before the file itself has been fully uploaded yet. But that is desired as I don't want to process, say, some gigabyte-large files into filesystem, and return 413 response afterwards - I want to cut them before any processing other than detecting their size.

So how to accomplish this in GCP (load balancer - apache - tomcat) environment?

Comment: I have the same experience.  2 questions: a) was this the L4 or L7 load balancer?, b) did you come up with a workaround?

Comment: Yes, I am validating file size on client with javascript :)